# Libpcap example doesnt work but project builds in eclipse?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, unix, libpcap

I am running the following libpcap example on Ubuntu, within eclipse:

http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *dev, errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    if (dev == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n", errbuf);
        return(2);
    }
    printf("Device: %s\n", dev);
    return(0);
}
```

I included the library path to the libpcap.a file in the eclipse settings for the GCC C++ linker. When I build the project I get:

g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -o"test"  ./src/test.o   -llibpcap.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibpcap.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1

I dont see why the path is /usr/bin/ld when I set it to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" within the linker library search path (libraries -L)? I also set (libraries -l) within GCC C++ linker to "libpcap.a"

Do I need to set both? Have I done this correctly? My pcap files are located at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Interestingly if I write non-pcap C++ but include pcap.h the code builds with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

OK you need to enter 'pcap' in the top window for the -l argument and then put your directory to the pcap files in the bottom window -L on eclipse, these are both within the GCC C++ Linker library section.

Comment: Yes - when specifying a library, you don't give `.a` in the name (the library doesn't necessarily have a name ending with `.a`, as it might be a dynamically-linked library, where the suffix might be `.so` or something such as that), and you leave out the "lib" at the beginning of the name (-l *xxx* searches for "libxxx").